# CircuiTikZ TikZ TeX in browser javascript

Tags: latex, tex, tikz

I've used MathJax for TeX/LaTeX maths & equations but how do I do so for electrical circuits using CircuiTikZ or any other suggestions?

I want to create electrical circuit diagrams (not just symbols) using TeX like CircuiTikZ.

Any recommendations are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Check out https://i.upmath.me/

It provides an option to embed a script into your page, similar to MathJax

```
<script src="//i.upmath.me/latex.js"></script>
```

However, that script connects to upmath's server and the processing from LaTeX to image is done serverside, so you are reliant on their service.